Do you have to use Identity for authentication in .NET Applications or is it just best practice? (MAUI in particular)
I'm a little confused around the purpose of Identity in .NET and what purpose it serves. Currently to date I have only developed some small internal applications where security isn't much of a concern overall however we just wanted to restrict what some people can do based on who they are and we've just made use of Windows authentication for our ASP.NET applications.
I am soon going to be developing a mobile application using .NET MAUI however this is going to be a customer facing application and I am currently looking into the best way of going about authentication and authorization in this context. I understand that any database request should not be handled by the application directly and instead should be handled by a Web API which I will develop separately as an ASP.NET Core Web API however my personal experience with logins has only been storing a username and relevant details in a SQL database once the Windows login has already been identified and I'm unsure of what route to go down for full logins.
Most of the Microsoft documentation around AspNetCore Identity references Microsoft Entra however again I am unsure if this is a requirement or just their suggestion as it's their product. Ideally I would like to just store the logins in a SQL database as prior but I understand that some security considerations need to be made as it will be customer facing and will involve passwords.
Unfortunately I have little to no experience with application security so I am unaware of how malicious users can get around security when it comes to mobile applications and APIs
Many thanks.
I have done research across the Microsoft documentation and various forums however I haven't managed to get any understanding of best practices and requirements with authentication.

There are hundreds of different ways to implement authentication.  The specific one you pick depends on your requirements.

Questions containing words "best" can usually only be answered by opinion (unless it's about animated series, where Spiderman 1994 wins no contest), and are therefor off-topic for SO

@sam It makes sense from a practical perspective to seek out a "best" solution that covers your environment from the frontend to the backend. In my experience you are going to have to manage several layers of security, not one. Think of it as if you need to secure your refrigerator. Starting at the street, you put up a gate but have to leave a key so Amazon can drop off a package. Now you must have a different lock for the front door, but have to leave a key for the handyman. Now you must have a different lock for the refrigerator. Three locks!!! Yes, three locks to secure that roast beef.

@siggemannen I was more referring to the phrase best-practice. By this I mean is it a requirement for proper security of an application or is this just a ready-made implementation that helps with adhering to security standards.

@BillRuhl Ah right okay, it seems the security front of applications is even more complicated than I imagined. I haven't needed to make many security considerations in the past for my applications as they've all been intranet only web applications.

If I were you I will start with the customer requirements and expectations. How will the customer users login to the app?
What they know -> e.g. password,
What they have -> e.g. client certificate on the device,
What they are -> e.g. finger print,
then I will check if I want to reinvent an authentication system or reuse an existing one

Another requirement is, do the users have to logon to an online backend? How will the users logon if the BE is not reachable?

another requirement, after the user logs on successfully. How long will this logon be valid? consider your banking app, you usually get logged of automatically after 5 inactive  minutes?
